# Will the BITS service follow HTTP redirects

Tags: iis, bits-service

I have a server that is serving files to several windows clients using the Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS).  If I would like to direct those clients to another server, could I do that by configuring IIS to return an HTTP redirect response to the new service?

Would that work for files that are in progress (but accessed via a RANGE request).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question was "Yes" :)